# Error Passing JSON to PHP to write to file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Ok so I have spent several hours researching solutions but none of them fix the issue.  I assume it is something stupid, but I am fairly new to PHP so I apologize if I am just missing something small.  I have a form in my index.php file that when the save button is clicked, the form data is collected and made into a JSON, which is then passed to a PHP file to be written to the file and downloaded.  I have tested what I could think of.  when I call gettype on the json being passed the returned type is string, so I am not sure why nothing is showing when I write it to the file.  If I write to the file by calling `fwrite($fh, "some text")` it shows in the file.  I am still generating an error of `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: myData in /var/www/html/UTSAForm/php/save.php on line 4` , although I do not get why since I have seen multiple code snippets where the ajax request is formatted the same way. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="top_bar">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="save();" >Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal">
          Open
        </button>
    </div>
<div class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Reivew Period</label>
            <label for="review_period_from">From</label>
            <input type="text" name="review_period_from" id="review_period_from">
            <label for="review_period_to">To</label>
            <input type="text" name="review_period_to" id="review_period_to">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employee_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" clsas="form-control" id="employee_name" placeholder="Employee Name">
            <label for="employee_title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" clsas="form-control" id="employee_title" placeholder="Employee Title">
            <label for="employee_id">EMPL ID</label>
            <input type="text" clsas="form-control" id="employee_id" placeholder="Employee ID">
            <label for="job_code">Job Code</label>
            <input type="text" clsas="form-control" id="job_code" placeholder="Job Code">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function save(){
    createJSON();
    // var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    // console.log(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/save.php',
        data: {'myData':JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            window.location = 'php/save.php';
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to save file");
        }
    });
}

function createJSON(){
jsonObj = [];

$('.form input').each(function(){
    var field = this.id;
    var input = $(this).val();

    item = {};
    item ["field"] = field;
    item ["input"] = input;

    jsonObj.push(item);
});
```

}

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = "formData.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, "w"); 
$json = $_POST['myData'];
fwrite($fh, $json);

// set the headers, so that
// the browser knows to expect a .txt file download.
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

// set Cache headers, to minimize the
// risk of the browser using old versions of the data.
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");

// print out the file data for
// the browser to open or save.
readfile($file);

exit;
```

?>

UPDATE:

Fixed, at least it is functional, not sure if it is still the proper method to achieve the desired result.  Thanks to @nishanth-matha though.  Fixed the code to the following:

JS (Ajax call)

```
    function save(){
    createJSON();
    // console.log(jsonObj);
    // var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    // console.log(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/save.php',
        data: {'myData':JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            window.location = 'php/downloadData.php';
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to save file");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP save.php

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['myData'];
if(json_decode($json) != null){
    // echo "valid json";
    $file = "formData.txt";
    $fh = fopen($file, "w"); 
    fwrite($fh, $json);
    fclose($fh);

    exit;
}else{
    echo "Invalid json";
}
```

?>

PHP downloadData.php

```
<?php
    // echo "valid json";
    $file = "formData.txt";

    // set the headers, so that
    // the browser knows to expect a .txt file download.
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

    // set Cache headers, to minimize the
    // risk of the browser using old versions of the data.
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");

    // print out the file data for
    // the browser to open or save.
    readfile($file);

    exit;
```

?>

Comment: You have `jsonObj = [];` defined inside the createJSON() scope. Then in save you are trying to reference it as a global var. That won't work. Start by defning `jsonObj[]` as a global variable.

Comment: @MarkSkayff   I see now that from looking at the code the jsonObj variable should not be global and not be accessible, so I am not sure why it is.  but I am going to make it global and see if I can figure out later why it is working when it obviously should not be.

Comment: It's ok if it's global. Global variables can be seen inside functions too.

Comment: Sorry I mean that it is not global.  I had it only declared inside the save function, but it was being accessed successfully from outside the function, which doesn't make sense since it shouldn't have existed outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in your JS:

Firstly, your error `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: myData in /var/www/html/UTSAForm/php/save.php on line 4` is due to the redirect to `save.php` you're trying in your `ajax success` function. Due to which your php runs `save.php` script again only to discover that `POST` variable `myDATA` isn't available anymore as you're simply redirecting the url not posting anything.

Second, `jsonObj` isn't defined in your ajax call. I think you want to return a value from `createJSON` and use it in ajax call, if so, you need to do the following:

```
function save(){
    var jsonObj = createJSON();
    // var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    // console.log(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/save.php',
        data: {'myData':JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#result').html(data);
            //window.location = 'php/save.php';
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to save file");
        }
    });
}

function createJSON(){
  jsonObj = [];

  $('.form input').each(function(){
    var field = this.id;
    var input = $(this).val();

    item = {};
    item ["field"] = field;
    item ["input"] = input;

    jsonObj.push(item);
  });
  return jsonObj;
}
```

In HTML add this line:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
try{
$file = "formData.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, "w"); 
$json = $_POST['myData'];
fwrite($fh, $json);

// set the headers, so that
// the browser knows to expect a .txt file download.
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

// set Cache headers, to minimize the
// risk of the browser using old versions of the data.
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");

// print out the file data for
// the browser to open or save.
readfile($file);
echo "Successfully downloaded"

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: JS is global.  I tested the jsonObj variable in the save function, it is correct.  I also tested the $json variable in the php file and echo back the contents of the variable.  So I know that in the save.php file $json is a string that represents the JSON, assuming the gettype() function is returning correctly.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much.  Makes perfect sense now.  I am not sure if I fixed it the correct way, but I just split the logic of writing the file and downloading the file into two separate files.  So the ajax calls sends the JSON and writes it to the file, and then the success function calls the php script to download it.

Comment: Well if you're looking to improve your code...I'd say if you're ONLY writing plain form data to a file, and downloading it (ie, no reason to access the server) then you don't need PHP at all. That could all be done with JS alone. At least I'd have done that way

Comment: I am using PHP because the user will actually be downloading the data later and then uploading it back to the form.  Just experimenting now to get a handle on the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `jsonObj = [];` as a global var in your Javascript and it'll be ok, like this:

```
jsonObj = [];

function save(){
    createJSON();
    // var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    // console.log(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/save.php',
        data: {'myData':JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           // console.log(data);
            window.location = 'php/save.php';
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Failed to save file");
        }
    });
 }

function createJSON(){

    $('.form input').each(function(){
        var field = this.id;
        var input = $(this).val();

        item = {};
        item ["field"] = field;
        item ["input"] = input;

        jsonObj.push(item);
     });
}
```